# Delete polkit rule

Tags: uninstall, policykit

I have followed this article

https://devanswers.co/how-to-fix-authentication-is-required-to-create-a-color-profile-managed-device-on-ubuntu-20-04-20-10/

Now I am no longer able to remove users, uninstall apps. Those commands are giving me trouble could some one help me to reverse those actions.

Thanks in advance